# How to add a descriptive object to object repository in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

In UFT, if I'm creating a descriptive object via code by manually specifying various micclass and value, Can that object be added to an existing object repository (*.tsr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptive Object is nothing but creating the object manually via code i.e making an object(**not recording it or adding via object spy**) and assigning it properties.

The same thing can be done in Object repository by using the Define New Test Object option. In the Object Repository Manager (or Object Repository) window from menu bar select Object->Define New Test Object and then select the all the properties than you want to assign to that object.

Please go through the below link for reference:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9dc5d3/1/

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. But you can add an object to the object repository by accessing Resources>> Object Spy>> Pointing hand>> Click on the object need to be added>> click add to repository(on top in object spy window). After adding you can just drag the object in to your script and it will generate the correct hierarchy.

UFT ver 12.02

Comment: We can add it and it has been mentioned in the previous answer how to do it

Comment: The questions is if we can or how to add a descriptive object to the OR? What you mentioned was adding the object to the repository by using OR approach. You can manipulate the object after adding it in the OR but you simply can not add a descriptor to the Repository .